# How to Install SSL on Apache2/Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ssl, apache-2.4

I am sorry if my question title seems like others / repost, but i already find same question and found no solutions.

I just buy GeoTrust QuickSSL and I want to setup SSL on my `Amazon EC2 Instance`.

Here is my config `001-mysite-ssl.conf` that I save on `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and then make symlink to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost mysite.com:443>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.com

            DocumentRoot /var/www/html

            #LogLevel info ssl:warn

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-mysite-ssl.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-mysite-ssl.log combined

            SSLEngine on

            #   MySite SSL & Key File
            SSLCertificateFile      "/usr/local/ssl/certs/mysite_com.crt"
            SSLCertificateKeyFile   "/usr/local/private/mysite.com.key"

            #   Certificate Authority (CA):
            SSLCACertificateFile "/usr/local/certs/mysite_com.ca-bundle"

            SSLProtocol     TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
            SSLCipherSuite  "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4"

            <Directory "/var/www/html">
                    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
                    AllowOverride All
                    Require all granted

                    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
                            Require all granted
                            SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
                    </FilesMatch>
            </Directory>

            ServerSignature Off
            ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/$1

            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>

            #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
            BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
            # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
            BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

    </VirtualHost>
```

and I got this on my error log `error-mysite-ssl.log`:

```
 [Tue Aug 11 08:04:34.450708 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 25086:tid 139975196800896] AH01909: ec2-57-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

I am sure I place my SSL Certificate, SSL Key & CA Bundle on path as I configured above and make permission to SSL Certificate & CA Bundle to 640 and SSL Key to 400 only. Even I tried to change permission to 766, doesn't work either. And I am sure I register Common Name (CN) exactly as `mysite.com` (without www, just domain.TLD).

When I tried to access, it give me result: `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` on Google Chrome. When I use Firefox, it give me error like this `Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long`.

Oh, I running Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and Apache as my webserver.

Please kindly give me some ideas / advice to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `Amazon EC2` has nothing to do with my problem, because I already allow port 443 via management console, so that port 443 can be access from outside.

The solution for this problem is I forgot that my instance configured as dedicated IP, and yes only single public IP assigned to this instance for single domain. So, the correct configuration is:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # I change mysite.com to *:443
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ....
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

That's solve problem, at the moment. If you or another person having the same problem with me, please check `VirtualHost` with your domain and 443 port is opened.

If your instance configuration allow single IP for multi domain, you should keep configuration like this

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost domainA.com:443>
    ....
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

And don't forget to setup / configure DNS on local instance to support this domain to be run SSL properly.